# Symfony replace the OR word with the pipe character

Tags: symfony

Symfony is replacing the OR word of my parameter value by a pipe caracter (ROLE_MENU_SUPP|T_EDITION ) in the http call that I made for my API. Here's a stack trace

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.name AS 
nom_2 FROM roles t0 WHERE t0.name = ?' 
with params ["ROLE_MENU_SUPPORT_EDITION"]:

Execution failed for request: GET 
/app_dev.php/api/roles?name=ROLE_MENU_SUPP|T_EDITION 
HTTP/1.1: HTTPCode 204, body
```

Here's the API method:

```
    /**
 * @Rest\View(statusCode=Response::HTTP_NO_CONTENT)
 * @Rest\Get("/roles")
 */
public function getAllEntitiesAction(Request $request)
{
    $filtre = array();

    if ($request->get("name")) {
        $filtre = array(
            'name' => $request->get("name")
        );
    }
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    return $em->getRepository($this->entity)->findBy($filtre);
}
```

Comment: I don't think that is your problem, because of `with params ["ROLE_MENU_SUPPORT_EDITION"]` - seems to be OK. `name` shouldn't be `nom`?

Comment: it is not the case, i've just tried to translate the column in english

Comment: I mean your  what you have in `$filtre` as key should be the same as in the columns of the DB.

Comment: Yes, and it's the case, i've just adapte my example to ask the question here in StackOverFlow

Comment: ok, can you provide us the output of `$request->get("name")` or better a `var_dump($filtre)`

Comment: it's ROLE_MENU_SUPPORT_EDITION, but i don't know why they convert the OR in a pipe character on the Http call

Comment: I think that happens just in the error displayer, because as you said the value of `$request->get("name")` is `ROLE_MENU_SUPPORT_EDITION` and as you can see in the first part of the error `with params ["ROLE_MENU_SUPPORT_EDITION"]` when it calls the in db it's also ok. What about the `var_dump($filtre)`?

Answer (score 0):

Tru to put ROLE_MENU_SUPPORT_EDITION in cuotes